# Multilevel-CCREM model with standardized predictors

Tags: multilevel-analysis, metafor

### Background:

I'm conducting a multilevel metanalysis to see if different types of magnetic fields, with different intensities and exposure duration, affect plant growth parameters. I have effect sizes (Response ratio, n = 81), nested within outcomes (Fresh weight of the plant, to account for comparisons using the same control group within studies. Fresh weight is also the **treatment value**), nested within studies and species, which are **crossed**. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
Author  Species  Intensity  Exposure  Fresh-weight  RR  NU  M   PL
 1        8         1          1           1        1   1   0   1
 1        2         1          1           2        2   1   0   1
 2        3         2          2           3        3   0   1   0
 2        3         2          3           4        4   0   1   0
 2        3         2          4           5        5   0   1   0
 3        4         3          2           6        6   1   0   0
 3        4         4          2           7        7   1   0   0
 3        4         5          2           8        8   1   0   0
 3        4         6          2           9        9   1   0   0
 4        2         6          3           10       10  0   1   1
 4        2         7          4           11       11  0   1   1
 4        2         6          3           12       12  0   1   1
 4        2         7          4           13       13  0   1   1
...      ...      ...         ...        ...       ...  ...  ...
```

**Important**
All data have unique IDs. For Mods section, I used the raw value of the predictors. NU, M, and PL are dummy variables for whether it is a non-uniform or uniform magnetic field (NU), whether a magnet or electromagnet produced the magnetic field (M), whether exposure initiated in a seed state or a plant state (PL).

Summarising, I have 81 effect sizes, nested within outcomes (fresh weights), nested within 15 studies and 12 species. To model this, I used the following code:

```
MLM.fw <- rma.mv(RR,
                 sv,
                 random = list(~ 1 | Author/Fresh-Weight,
                               ~ 1 | Species),
                 data = fw2,
                 method = "REML")
```

For mods addition, I considered Intensity, Exposure, and the dummy variables as **Level 1 predictors**. Using AIC to test the models, I found out that it was best to use all the numerical variables and just one dummy variable at a time. For this question, I'll be using NU:

```
mods = ~ NU*z.int*z.exp
```

**Where z.int and z.exp are the standardized versions of Intensity and Exposure raw values, respectively**

This formula gave me the following results:

```
Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 81; method: REML)

logLik  Deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc 
33.5652  -67.1305  -45.1305  -19.9354  -40.8026   

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed    factor 
sigma^2.1  0.0184  0.1356     15     no     Author 
sigma^2.2  0.0110  0.1050     74     no  Author/Fresh-weight 
sigma^2.3  0.0000  0.0000     12     no    Species 

Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 73) = 402.8025, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficients 2:8):
QM(df = 7) = 77.0209, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

                 estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
intrcpt            0.1863  0.0577   3.2277  0.0012   0.0732   0.2994   ** 
NU                 0.6142  0.1233   4.9805  <.0001   0.3725   0.8559  *** 
z.int              0.0554  0.0168   3.3064  0.0009   0.0226   0.0882  *** 
z.exp              0.0851  0.0247   3.4456  0.0006   0.0367   0.1336  *** 
NU:z.int           0.1828  1.3335   0.1371  0.8910  -2.4309   2.7965      
NU:z.exp          -0.3095  0.1100  -2.8142  0.0049  -0.5251  -0.0940   ** 
z.int:z.exp        0.0866  0.0227   3.8205  0.0001   0.0422   0.1311  *** 
NU:z.int:z.exp    -0.5439  3.2187  -0.1690  0.8658  -6.8523   5.7646      

---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Questions**

1. ¿Is this a good model to try to explain the phenomenon I'm researching? and if so:
   ¿How can I start building my regression equation? For example, I noticed that NU main effect is rather stronger or more important than NU:z.exp, but the interaction predictor is also significant. ¿Does that mean that NU main effect is no longer needed in the equation?
2. I wanted to apply robust() to account for **correlated standard errors** between *labs* (same authors publishing related articles in different years) or model mis-specification. ¿Would I be **over-penalizing** my model, considering that nesting ES within outcomes, should be already doing that?
3. I had a third variable but because of moderate correlation, the model would leave it out. ¿How can I include it anyway?

Thanks in advance for your answers, and don't hesitate to point out any mistakes I may be doing.